# iPhone 5 flashlight strength

Tags: iphone

After having had my bag stolen, I am putting together a new EDC kit, and am wanting to include a flashlight. I want it to be at least as powerful as that featured on the iPhone 5. Does anyone know how powerful the one on the iPhone 5 is, measured in Lumen?

Answer (score 2):

My apologies for not being able to give you a 100% answer. But I did find a informative post about the LED strength of an iPhone 4 (should be the same for the 5 - not the 5S).

> Using a combination of direct and reflection lux meter readings, and comparing the same readings to lights of known lumen output, I'd roughly estimate the iPhone 4 LED is about 5 to 10 lumens in normal continuous use.
>
> It briefly gets significantly brighter when used as a camera flash, but it's too brief to measure with my lux meter. I'd estimate it's about 4x brighter, which is around 40 lumens, but only for about 1/4 second.

[Source](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?282022-iPhone-4-LED-flash-flashlight&p=3575408&viewfull=1#post3575408)

I hope this helps!