# How many watts in iPhone LED flashlight

Tags: iphone

I have a few 1 watt and 10 watt LED's laying around. I want to compare them to the iPhone 5 flashlight. In [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129388/iphone-5-flashlight-strength), I saw a lumen rating, but I want a watt rating. Does anybody know the wattage of the iPhone 5 flashlight?

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the lumens value of the light source, you can use the following calculator to determine its equivalent rating in Watts:

http://www.rapidtables.com/calc/light/lumen-to-watt-calculator.htm

Comment: Thanks, although the question I referenced to does not seem to have a very high certainty, and only knows the iPhone 4 is about 5-10 lumens, which is .2 watts max. That does not seem a lot compared to the brightness

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I read your original question that stated that you knew the lumens rating and wanted Watts. Best of luck finding the answer you seek! It's my understanding (though not certain) that our iPhone 5 has ~10 lumens capacity. That seems about right given rough brightness comparisons with more powerful LED flashlights here in the house.

Answer (score -1):

it outputs enough light to power a solar powered joule thief circuit if you take the purple colored panel out of a garden light the blue Polycrystalline Silicon panels don’t seem to work ‍♂️ (i got increased voltage but no current from it)